# How to find out if a user has actually Tweeted?

Tags: twitter

I have a website which allows the user to tweet using a specific hashtag, would their be anyway to actually find out if the user has really tweeted.

I was thinking of looking at the timestamps and just working out the difference between right now and when the last tweet was made but that's not really professional.

I know Facebook allows you to do this quite easily but I'm struggling to figure out the best solution.

any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Retrieve the tweets of the user in question
2. Scan the text of each tweet, looking for your hashtag.
3. If you know when they visited your website, compare the time of the visit to the time of the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ensure the users tweets, then tweet for the user by requesting authorization and then tweeting via the API. This will still not stop the users from deleting the tweet.

If you plan any reward scheme, you won't be able to force users to keep the tweet (and probably the twitter API ToS forbid such things).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Twitter STREAM API. One of the public stream is the [Filter Stream](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter).

This stream give the possibility to specify keywords/hashtags that you want to follow in live.

You can simply track the hashtag that you want and then you will receive in live all the tweets posted with your hashtag.

You can then simply check the json property `user` and compare the `id`/`screen_name` to the user you want to identify.